# View list of registered document providers

Tags: file-system

How do I check in Android which applications have registered their document providers? I hope no code is needed (I need it from user perspective), but if that's the only way then I can attempt that.

Comment: Are you talking about apps with "content providers" (app acts as data source) or are you talking about apps that have registered file types (mime types), e.g. a PDF viewer that can receive and display pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

I assume were referring to the file types the different apps can open.

On a rooted device you can get the list the following way:

The mime types and the applications for the default user are stored in the file `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml`

Therefore you can execute the following PC to get the full list on a smartphone connected via USB (an enabled ADB):

```
adb shell "su -c 'cat /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml'"
```